# How do I use the bootstrap datepicker in vue3

Tags: datepicker, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

Im using vue3, and bootstrap 5. I want to add a datepicker to my app.
The datepicker was in bootstrap4, but it appears to me that bootstrap5 doesn't have it. I'm suprised that its not there, I don't understand why they would remove it.

Anyway, I tried to use [vue3-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-datepicker). And I use it like this:

```
<div>
    <datepicker v-model="form.birth_day" />
</div>
<script>
import Datepicker from 'vue3-datepicker'
....
```

This is just the way I thought I should use it. But I'm a bit new to vue.
It doesn't work. There is no error, but also no datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
  <Datepicker v-model="form.birth_day" />
</div>
<script>
import Datepicker from 'vue3-datepicker'
export default {
  name: 'Register',
  components: {
    Datepicker
  },
 ...
```